# How to automatically round off the contents in a table in LateX?

Tags: latex

I was trying to get at table in LateX which I did, But I wanted round off the data in table and I couldn't find a way. I am giving the LateX code

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\resizebox{16cm}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    Sl.No & Distance d (cm) & Count in 30s & Corrected Count in 30s  & Net count rate & Rd\^2 & 1/d\^2 & Error \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 4130 & 4100 & 136.6666667 & 546.6666667 & 2500 & 430.1371795 \\ \hline
    2 & 2.5 & 3250 & 3220 & 107.3333333 & 670.8333333 & 1600 & 305.9705129 \\ \hline
    3 & 3 & 2637 & 2607 & 86.9 & 782.1 & 1111.111111 & 194.7038462 \\ \hline
    4 & 3.5 & 2217 & 2187 & 72.9 & 893.025 & 816.3265306 & 83.7788462 \\ \hline
    5 & 4 & 1806 & 1776 & 59.2 & 947.2 & 625 & 29.6038462 \\ \hline
    6 & 4.5 & 1586 & 1556 & 51.86666667 & 1050.3 & 493.8271605 & 73.4961538 \\ \hline
    7 & 5 & 1296 & 1266 & 42.2 & 1055 & 400 & 78.1961538 \\ \hline
    8 & 5.5 & 1112 & 1082 & 36.06666667 & 1091.016667 & 330.5785124 & 114.2128205 \\ \hline
    9 & 6 & 934 & 904 & 30.13333333 & 1084.8 & 277.7777778 & 107.9961538 \\ \hline
    10 & 6.5 & 789 & 759 & 25.3 & 1068.925 & 236.6863905 & 92.1211538 \\ \hline
    11 & 7 & 753 & 723 & 24.1 & 1180.9 & 204.0816327 & 204.0961538 \\ \hline
    12 & 7.5 & 632 & 602 & 20.06666667 & 1128.75 & 177.7777778 & 151.9461538 \\ \hline
    13 & 8 & 592 & 562 & 18.73333333 & 1198.933333 & 156.25 & 222.1294871 \\ \hline
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & Average of Rd\^2 & ~ & Average of Error  \\ \hline
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & 976.8038462 & ~ & 160.6452663 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%}
\end{table}
```

Is there a way to automatically round off the contents of the table?

Comment: Have a look at the siunitx package

Comment: Don't ever use `\resizebox` for content which contains text. Use an appropriate font size instead!

Comment: Can you make a compileable [mre]?

Answer (score -1):

#### Use the `numprint` package.

The `numprint` package does what you are looking for, but you have to be careful when insterting text in your table.

You can set the following options for the rounding off:

- `\npdecimalsign{.}` which tells what is the decimal separator.
- `\nprounddigits{X}` which sets the number of digits after the decimal separator.

For setting the column type you have to use the command `n{B}{A}`, where B is the number of digits before the separator and A is the number of digits after the separator (which seems to be actually override by `\nprounddigits{X}`).

Be aware that you have to put the text in curly brackets, for example in the headings of the table.

Your code becomes thus

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{numprint}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{2}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering

        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|n{4}{2}|n{4}{2}|n{4}{2}|n{4}{2}}
            
            {Sl.No} & {Distance d (cm)} & {Count in 30s} & {Corrected Count in 30s}  & {Net count rate} & {Rd\^2} & {1/d\^2} & {Error }\\ 
            \hline
            1 & 2 & 4130 & 4100 & 136.6666667 & 546.6666667 & 2500 & 430.1371795 \\ 
            \hline
            2 & 2.5 & 3250 & 3220 & 107.3333333 & 670.8333333 & 1600 & 305.9705129 \\ 
            \hline
            3 & 3 & 2637 & 2607 & 86.9 & 782.1 & 1111.111111 & 194.7038462 \\ 
            \hline
            4 & 3.5 & 2217 & 2187 & 72.9 & 893.025 & 816.3265306 & 83.7788462 \\
            \hline
            5 & 4 & 1806 & 1776 & 59.2 & 947.2 & 625 & 29.6038462 \\ \hline
            6 & 4.5 & 1586 & 1556 & 51.86666667 & 1050.3 & 493.8271605 & 73.4961538 \\ 
            \hline
            7 & 5 & 1296 & 1266 & 42.2 & 1055.0 & 400 & 78.1961538 \\ 
            \hline
            8 & 5.5 & 1112 & 1082 & 36.06666667 & 1091.016667 & 330.5785124 & 114.2128205 \\ 
            \hline
            9 & 6 & 934 & 904 & 30.13333333 & 1084.8 & 277.7777778 & 107.9961538 \\ 
            \hline
            10 & 6.5 & 789 & 759 & 25.3 & 1068.925 & 236.6863905 & 92.1211538 \\ 
            \hline
            11 & 7 & 753 & 723 & 24.1 & 1180.9 & 204.0816327 & 204.0961538 \\ 
            \hline
            12 & 7.5 & 632 & 602 & 20.06666667 & 1128.75 & 177.7777778 & 151.9461538 \\ 
            \hline
            13 & 8 & 592 & 562 & 18.73333333 & 1198.933333 & 156.25 & 222.1294871 \\ \hline
            {~} & {~} & {~} & {~} & {~} & {Average of Rd\^2} & {~} & {Average of Error}  \\ 
            \hline
            {~} & {~} & {~} & {~} & {~} & 976.8038462 & ~ & 160.6452663 \\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you need more details, check the documentation [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/numprint).

---

If I may suggest an improvement, use the package `booktabs` for a better appearance of tables.